# Fire jQuery on resize and browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-size

I was having issues with background-size in IE, so I found a JavaScript that allows it to work in IE, but I only want background-size applied if the screen width goes below 768 pixels.

Here is my current script:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768)
       jQuery('#header').css( "background-size", "cover" );
});
```

This works once you start resizing, but once you get below 768 it doesn't remove background-size and the initial state does not have background size either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why you use JQ? You can do this with @media in your css file

Comment: `if($(window).width() > 768) do one thing;
else do other;` It should be this simple, or am I missing something?

Comment: Like I said, background-size does not work in IE so I have to use JavaScript.

Comment: @user13286 , if background-size doesn't work on IE it will not work on IE if you used it like that :) , try another way because you are doing the same thing as CSS

Comment: It works fine, I've already tested it. The Javascript I am using was specifically made for this use. https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is nearly correct. All you need to do is add an else.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 768) {
       jQuery('#header').css( "background-size", "cover" );
    } else {
       jQuery('#header').css( "background-size", "whatever" );
    }
});
```

I'm concerned about you writing all over the place `jQuery` so what you can do is also:

```
jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM ready and secured jQuery's $ alias

  // Use freely $ alias
  var $header = $('#header'); // Cache your selectors
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $header.css({backgroundSize:$(this).width()>768?"cover":"whatever"});
  });

  // Other $ code here

});
```

Comment: Thanks, if I just put an empty set of quotation marks will that just remove the background-size property?

Answer (score 2):

No need to javascript it, just use css and mediaqueries. **This is a lot faster than jQuery/javascript**, and is exactly for this type of situation. Especially on mobiles you will can notice this when rotating the device. Also, older browsers will be less jaggy on resize.

```
#header{
    /* style for the older browsers, also basic info like maybe height/width */
} 

@media screen {
    #header{
        background-size : cover;
        /* Other css, not defined in the #header{} above, for modern browsers */
    } 
}
```

Small note: Mediaqueries will not work on older browsers. You can use this to your advantage and style the modern browsers only in the mediaquery.
Please bare in mind, background-size doesn't work, so you can not use that

Comment: Added the reverse version so IE8 wont be a problem

Comment: I removed the +1 for a second just cause your answer implies that `IE8` has a clue about `background-size` ... So both ways flipped or non makes still no sense to me ;) Hope it helps (P.S. I'd just leave something like "If you don't need support for older browsers... bla bla")

Comment: I removed the reverse method, and added a note

Comment: Don't downvote and dont comment. But I can see your comment in my inbox, and I've updated my answer to a solution which works in both types of browsers

Comment: I'm not the downvoter brosky... You'll never know who downvoted focus on other questions rather than on one downvote. Or improve your answer, sometimes downvoters come back to see if the answer is improved to regain the lost -1 point.